# ngAnimate slide down/up with non-fix height

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-animate

I would like to create a simple slide down/up animation for a div. The problem is that it only works when the div has fix height.

**index.html**

```
<div id="guildDetails" class="animate-show" ng-show="guildDetails.show">
</div>
```

**style.css**

```
.ng-hide-add, .ng-hide-remove {
    display: block !important;
}
.animate-show {
    transition: .3s linear all;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.animate-show.ng-hide {
    height:0;
}
```

It just works, but the content in that div isn't static, so sometimes that 500px is just too big and sometimes it's just too small. I tried to set the height to auto but, if I set it, then it won't work.

How can I animate it if I don't want to use fixed height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is angular plugin [ng-slide-down](https://github.com/TheRusskiy/ng-slide-down) for solving this problem. I have used it in my project successfully for dynamic content slide down.

Copying the code from example here

```
<div ng-click="widgetExpanded = !widgetExpanded" class="head">
    Click to slide in/out
  </div>
  <div ng-slide-down="widgetExpanded" lazy-render duration="1">
    <div class="content">
      Some awesome content here
    </div>
  </div>
```

Use `ng-slide-down="widgetExpanded"` with boolean property and update it for sliding the div up and down.

[JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/therusskiy/JR3C7/4/) example